# Is there a way to use an own frontend instead of keycloak login?

Tags: openid-connect, keycloak

I want to use an Angular >4 app that calls REST endpoints from Keycloak >4 to login.

Spoiler: No, I don't want to use a Keycloak theme, because Freemarker templates are far to static. I need some dynamic ressources and CDN magic.

So I used the "…/auth/realms/REALM/protocol/openid-connect/token" endpoint and get this as resonse:

```
{ 
  "access_token": "ey…"
  "expires_in":60,
  "not-before-policy":0,
  "refresh_expires_in":1800,
  "refresh_token":"ey…",
  "session_state": "…"
  "token_type":"bearer"
}
```

I don't really can figure out what to do with this `access_token` or `session_state`. Nether did I find an example to doing this.

Comment: You need to use a server side adapter and attach the token to every request you make. `because Freemarker templates are far to static`: You can still use angular in your custom login theme. Freemarker evaluates at server side, while JS frameworks do at client side. Using a theme you are allowed to write any JS you want and you follow the conventions of using the authorization code flow: https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/which-oauth-flow-to-use which is the safest choice for a web application.

Comment: At first thx! I don't want to make any request with this login app, I want to login in to another app that is secured by Keycloak. And this App has an adapter for Keycloak to make API Calls. The Only thing I want is being logged in.